# matmul: Input operand 1 has a mismatch in its core dimension 0, with gufunc signature

Tags: python

```
topology = [p, 4, 8, 16, 8, 4, 1]

neural_net = create_nn(topology, sigm)

l2_cost = (lambda Yp, Yr: np.mean((Yp - Yr) ** 2),
           lambda Yp, Yr: (Yp- Yr))



def train(neural_net, X, Y, l2_cost, lr=0.5):

  out = [(None, X)]
  
  #Foward pass
  for l, layer in enumerate(neural_net):
    

    z = out[-1][1] @ neural_net[l].W + neural_net[l].b
    a = neural_net[l].act_f[0](z)

    out.append((z, a))
  print(out[-1[1]])

train(neural_net, X, Y, l2_cost, 0.5)
```

this show me the next error

```
matmul: Input operand 1 has a mismatch in its core dimension 0, 
with gufunc signature (n?,k),(k,m?)->(n?,m?) (size 4 is different from 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing the rest of your code, in particular not knowing the `shape` of your matrices, my best guess is that you're trying to multiply together matrices whose dimensions don't match as they're supposed to.

Let me cite a passage from [this](https://online.stat.psu.edu/statprogram/reviews/matrix-algebra/arithmetic) article by PennState:

> To perform matrix multiplication, the first matrix must have the same number of columns as the second matrix has rows.

Whenever you're using the `@` operator you're telling Python that you're doing Matrix multiplication!

Let's take the following two matrices as an example:

```py
import numpy as np

X = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]])
Y = np.array([[7, 8, 9], [9, 10, 11]])
```

X has ha shape of (3, 2) whilst Y has a shape of (2, 3). This means that they can indeed be multiplied, and that the resulting matrix will have a (3, 3) shape.

```py
print(X @ Y)

######### Output #########
# [[ 25  28  31]
# [ 57  64  71]
# [ 89 100 111]]
##########################
```

Now let's say you tried transposing the matrix Y, that is, inverting its rows and cols, making it a (3, 2) matrix. What would you expect to happen?

Yes, you guessed it, Python would tell you that you're doing something wrong, as this operation is not allowed in Linear Algebra.

```py
# Matrix Multiplication between X and Y transposed
print(X @ Y.T)

######### Output #########
# ValueError: matmul: Input operand 1 has a mismatch in its core dimension 0
# with gufunc signature (n?,k),(k,m?)->(n?,m?) (size 3 is different from 2)
##########################
```

The only thing you should be doing, therefore, is simply checking your matrices dimensions with a command like `Y.shape` and correcting your mistake.